# rename the file name while generate the zip file

Tags: php, codeigniter, http, pdf, zip

Some pdf files are in my folder with user id. Whenever user select the rows in front end particular records are there or not checking and generate the zip file and download. But i want to replace pdf file name with user name?

For example in my folder 101.pdf is stored when i generate zip 101 change with user name smith.pdf file generate zip and download? how?

```
public function download_pdf()
{
    $createdzipname = 'reportszip';
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $this->zip->add_dir('zipfolder');
    $userIds=$this->input->post('user_ids');//userids are like 101,102,103
    $file_names=explode(',',$userIds);
    $files = $file_names;
    $i=0;
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
            $reportfile=$file;
            $s1=strlen($reportfile);
            $s2=9;
            $s3=$s2-$s1;
            $string_before=str_pad($value, $s3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
            $fileename=$string_before.$reportfile;
            $paths = base_url().'report/pdf/'.$fileename.'.pdf';    

        $this->zip->add_data('zipfolder/'.$paths,file_get_contents($paths));
             $i++;
        }
        $this->zip->download($createdzipname.'.zip');
    }
```

Comment: You can use `$newpaths = base_url().'report/pdf/'.$username.'.pdf'; rename($paths, $newpaths);`.

Comment: i didn't get @Ayush

Comment: Rename your `current file` to the `usename` and then send it to zip.

Comment: when i rename like this file downloaded but download corrupted file.
$paths = base_url().'report/pdf/'.$fileename.'.pdf';
if($fileename = '109.pdf')
{
 $username = 'smith.pdf';
$newpaths = base_url().'report/pdf/'.$username.'.pdf';
rename($paths, $newpaths); }

Comment: There is an error in your code. `$username = 'smith.pdf'; $newpaths = base_url().'report/pdf/'.$username.'.pdf';` This will translate to `$newpaths = smith.pdf'.pdf`. Change your username.

Comment: i already changed and tested still corrupted file download

Comment: can you test it on your server that the file is corrupt or not??

Comment: in my folder 109.pdf file is there with 2mb when i rename and zip above like smith.pdf file genrated with size is 0

Comment: Previously, was your zip files were generating correctly?? Can you check that the renamed filed is correct or not on the server??

Comment: Previously generated zip was correct.